# How can you \ Numbers like this?

Tags: graphics

[image]

I know how to write \frac{9}{20}

but how can you make a orange slash trough the number?

Answer (score 6):

It can be done with the`cancel` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
    \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{orange}}

    \begin{document}

        \[ \frac{\bcancel{\,9\,}}{\bcancel{20}}\cdot \frac{\bcancel{25}}{\bcancel{18}}\]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, I just figured out how to cross numbers on other topic already tho

but the orange colour is new ^^

can you show me how to do this in discord?

Comment: @user279680:  what do you mean with `in discord`?

Comment: With the "TeXit Bot" in Discord. It can show latex

Comment: U just need to write  ``$\frac{\bcancel{,5,}}{\bcancel{15}}=\frac{1}{3}$`` and then it shows the result

Comment: @user279680 Notice that Bernard added the line `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{orange}}` to their code. What this does is that it redefines `\CancelColor` to `\color{orange}`. If you'd like to achieve what Bernard did in any LaTeX compiler, such as the TeXit Discord bot, you'll want to add the renewcommand line before you use your cancel to ensure the color has been set to orange.